# how to send post request and get response in big5 using Apache HttpClient 4.5

Tags: java, apache, apache-httpclient-4.x

It is to send post request encodeing in big5 using Apache HttpClient 4.5. 
Java code is as follows, and the result shows the unreadable code like ???.
Please give some suggestions to fix it.

```````````````````````
   hpr803.getResps1("http://web-reg-server.803.org.tw/TRE/stepB1.asp");

  //the method to send post request and get response
  public void getResps1(String param) throws IOException{    
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> pairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    // Post request example hospital 803
   pairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("syear", "104"));
   pairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("smonth", "7"));
   pairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sday", "20"));
   pairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("eyear", "104"));
   pairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("emonth", "8"));
   pairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("eday", "5"));
   pairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("HospNO", "1"));
   pairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("SectNO", ""));
   pairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("EmpNO", ""));

     HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(param);
     //big5 code
     StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(URLEncodedUtils.format(pairList, "big5"));
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);

    //httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairList, "big5"));
    CloseableHttpClient demo = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(param);
    HttpResponse response = demo.execute(httpGet);
    String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "big5");
    response = demo.execute(httpPost);
    responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        System.out.println("responseString   big5 ~~~~~~~~~~     " +responseString);
    } else {
        System.out.println("response.getStatusLine   ``````````````````````  " +response.getStatusLine());
    }
}
```````````````````````

Comment: You should set the `Accept-charset` header in your request and set it's value to `big5`. Otherwise the server doe snot know that you can handle an big5 encoded response.

Comment: @Robert, html in http://web-reg-server.803.org.tw/TRE/stepB1.asp is: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=big5" /> should i set the header in java? how to set it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in your code. I have tried it and it works fine. It is in your console / Eclipse / IntelliJIdea, depends where you start it.
I have modified you code to write in a file:

```````````````````````
String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "big5");
    response = demo.execute(httpPost);
    //responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\test\\Big5Test.html");
        response.getEntity().writeTo(fos);
        fos.close();
    } else {
        System.out.println("response.getStatusLine   ``````````````````````  " +response.getStatusLine());
    }
```````````````````````

When I have open the file in Firefox everything was fine. Please try it on your system.